# Visual Studio 2019 VB Form don't open again

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

My project/solution of VS (VB) 2019 I was able to edit and publish till date. But now after uninstalling Visual Studio 2017, one of the form of my solution do not open and gives me error message:

> There is no editor available for XYZ.vb (my Form file name with full
>   path). Make sure the application for the file type (.vb) is installed.

I am able to open all other forms other then one in the same solution.

What and where can be the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to view the code or the designer? Look at your file in notepad and see any obvious differences from a file that is opening properly.

Comment: Try a repair on Visual Studio.

Comment: What kind of form is it? Check you've included the applicable workloads when installing VS2019. Eg. for WinForms you need to include .NET Desktop Development, for WebForms you need ASP.NET And Web Development.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you figure this out?